# Tomcat 6 not recognizing <url-mapping>

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I have what I think is the simplest possible
hello world example (see below). But when asking for
"http://localhost:8080/hello" thru firefox,
it gives me the
"The requested resource (/hello/) is not available"
error.

Environment:  newly installed tomcat 6.0.32 on Windows 7.

Other information:
1. None of the "similar questions" provides any clues.

1. From experimentation, it appears that tomcat is not
   doing the mapping from localhost:8080/hello to my servlet.
2. I set "<load-on-startup>"
   which showed me that the servlet's init entry was being
   called, but doGet() is never called.
3. The log files show no errors.
4. I have tried both starting tomcat with the hello
   directory already in webapps, with hello.war in
   webapps, and deploying using the manager application.
   All act the same way.

Some possibilities I have considered:

1. According to the documentation, I should
   not need to use a context.xml file, and my experiments
   with a context.xml produced the same resource not found
   error.
2. localhost:8080/hello should instead be
   localhost:8080/.../hello, but if so, then what is
   the ... supposed to be?
3. Trailing / (e.g. /hello versus /hello/). I changed
   the url-pattern to "/hello/*", but it fails the same
   way.

I assume the problem is something simple, but I cannot
see it.

[Added 8/8/2011]
The answers about using context.xml were correct; thanks.
In looking around, it appears that an alternate way
to achieve the same effect is to put this
into my web.xml file.

```
<context-param>
<param-name>ContextPath</param-name>
<param-value>/dts</param-value>
</context-param>
```

web.xml:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" version="2.4"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http:/java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd">
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>hello</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>test.HelloServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>hello</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/hello</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

HelloServlet.java:
    package test;

```
import java.io.*;

import javax.servlet.http.*;
import javax.servlet.*;

public class HelloServlet extends HttpServlet {

  public void init()
  {
    System.out.println("\nHelloServlet.init");
  }

  public void doGet (HttpServletRequest req,
                     HttpServletResponse res)
    throws ServletException, IOException
  {
    System.out.println("\nHelloServlet.doGet");
    PrintWriter out = res.getWriter();
    out.println("Hello, world!");
    out.close();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With a Java Servlet Application (part of, but not the total sum of Java EE - Java Enterprise Edition), applications have servlets under what is called a "context path".  This "context path" has to be specified in order to map any request to the application.

Apache Tomcat makes this context path pretty easy to configure, either via server.xml (not recommended) or individual context files (recommended).  Both ways specify where to find your web application directory (an unpacked web application archive, or WAR file) and where to place it on the server at a context path.

As Vlad has already said, if you deploy your war file into Tomcat's webapps directory and have automatic installation on (I believe it is on by default), Tomcat will unpack the .war into a directory under that location and use the war's name as its context path.  His example war file is named "helloapp.war", so, with the default settings, it would receive any request to `http://localhost:8080/helloapp` because its context path becomes helloapp.

Of course, once the request is sent to the context path, something needs to match against it.  That's where the web.xml comes in to play.  While it is possible to use the root as a matcher (every request to the context path gets handled by the same process), typically a pattern is used (such as *.do, *.action, etc), so that individual requests to the helloapp are easily distinguishable (it's easier to read and debug `http://localhost:8080/helloapp/login.action` and `http://localhost:8080/helloapp/doSomethingElse.action` than both being recognized via some parameters and the same path of `http://localhost:8080/helloapp` in my opinion)

So, the context path gets to your application, then your application has to do a lookup on the web.xml to see where to send the actual request.  In your example, if your webapp was deployed at the context path of helloapp, to access it with the proper mapping, you would simply append /hello, so the request becomes `http://localhost:8080/helloapp/hello`

Answer (score 2):

You are deploying your `hello` servlet in a webapp. Assuming the webapp is in a folder `helloapp` or in an archive `helloapp.war` in Tomcat's `webapps` directory then your sevlet would be accessible at `http://localhost:8080/helloapp/hello`

Answer (score 1):

You will either need to rename the package to ROOT.war (or the ROOT directory) or modify the ROOT.xml context.xml file to point to the hello folder.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to /hello/hello I bet you'll see your app. If you're using tomcat, use context.xml.
You may not need to use it for a webapp to work, but if you deploy under tomcat, things just work more coherently when you have a context.xml file.

In /yourtomcatinstall/webapps/hello/META-INF/ create a context.xml file with this information"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context path="/hello">
</Context>
```

And change the url mapping of your servlet in web.xml to / and/or /* you can have more than one url mapping for a servlet.

Comment: sorry, the original example was pasted from one of my own webapps. Technically, you could just change your url mapping to / but I would still add a context.xml to your webapp.

Comment: Also, if you don't have a context.xml set up. Whatever the .war filename is, that will be the root url. So if your war file's name is HelloServlet.war, tomcat will deploy it in the webapps/HelloServlet directory and your root url will be /HelloServlet. Therefore you will be able to access the servlet at: /HelloServlet/hello.

Comment: 1. /hello/hello did invoke the servlet. 2. adding the context.xml also worked; wish the documentation had been clearer on this, but oh well.